# I cannot start sessions for different user roles and restrict folders for logged out users

Tags: php, session

I am using a login script and I am trying to get my head around sessions with not much luck.

When the user logs in I want them redirecting to the relevant folder, here is my login script

```
  if (isset($_POST['btnLogOn'])) {  
        $email     = !empty($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
        $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;   
        $db=DB();
        $sql = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE  email = ? LIMIT 1";
        $stat = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stat->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stat->execute();
        $row = $stat->fetch();
        if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { 
            if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
                setcookie('email', $email, time() + 60 * 60 * 7);
                setcookie('password', $password, time() + 60 * 60 * 7);
            }
            {
          $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_role'] = $row['role'];
          switch($_SESSION['user_role']){
             case 'Admin':
                 $_SESSION['user_role'];
                 header( 'Location: admin');
                 break;
             case 'Advisor':
                 $_SESSION['user_role'] ;
                 header( 'Location: advisor');
                 break;
              case 'Tech':
                 $_SESSION['user_role'] ;
                 header( 'Location: tech');
                 break; 
                case 'User':
                 $_SESSION['user_role'];
                  // redirect to admin
                 header( 'Location: dashboard');
                 break; 
                }
```

I am not sure if the above code is correct and I am really struggling in what code to write in the header of each "named" folders.

I have tried a lot of messing with code below in the seperate headers  but it either keeps refreshing to the ../index.php or it lets me open the folder whether i am logged in or not

```
            session_start();
         $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_role'] = $row['role'];
            if(empty($_SESSION['user_role'])){
            header('Location: ../index.php');
            }
```

What I want to happen when the user logs on the role determines which folder to open and if no one is logged on they cannot open the folder

Hope that makes sense

Thanks
Molly

Comment: You have an extra '{' in code right here: `setcookie('password', $password, time() + 60 * 60 * 7);
            }
            {    //<<<` before the `$_SESSION['user_session']`

Comment: does each directory check if the user has proper session as well as proper role for to be in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you trying to implement. I current days, it is easy to use some frameworks or micro frameworks to cover some basic stuff under the hood which allow you to not recreate a bicycle over again . That is where you getting advantages. In your case if that is a template project i would do it this way:

**root of the project/index.php**

```
...

    if (isset($_POST['btnLogOn'])) {  
    
       ...//get find user if exist
    
       $domain = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
       if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { 
          if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
             setcookie('email', $email, time() + 60 * 60 * 7);
             setcookie('password', $password, time() + 60 * 60 * 7);
          }
          $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_role'] = $row['role'];
          switch($_SESSION['user_role']){
             case 'Admin':
                $dir = 'admin';
                break;
             case 'Advisor':
                $dir = 'advisor';
                break;
             case 'Tech':
                $dir = 'tech';
                break; 
             case 'User':
                $dir = 'dashboard';
                break;
             default:
                $dir = 'index.php';
           }
           header( 'Location: ' . $domain . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir);
        }
    }

...
```

and here:

**root directory/admin/index.php**

```
$domain = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
//check if user exist it is admin
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_session']) || (isset($_SESSION['user_role']) && $_SESSION['user_role'] != 'admin')){
    //it is not, redirect
    header( 'Location: ' . $domain . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php');
}
```

But it should be a lot more secured. Because right now this code is open for attacker. Good way to secure your code you can find in numerous materials on the web as well and here: [PHP Sessions in Depth](https://www.phparch.com/2018/01/php-sessions-in-depth/)

I would suggest you to try [Slim PHP micro framework](http://www.slimframework.com/), [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) or [Yii](https://www.yiiframework.com/) to enjoy work, and create new projects on PHP.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I took your advice and over the weekend I have turned my attention to MVC and I ask myself why didnt I do it before, once you understand it it is so much easier to fault find and so much easier to build code, I have spent over 2 years trying to learn php and my respect goes out to the people who fully understand it.